# Some sites not opening in firefox

Tags: 12.04, networking, browser

I am unable to open Yahoo hdfc and some other sites with Mozilla, Chromium
I tried:

1. changing DNS
2. enabling Java
3. reinstalling Firefox

Comment: Are you getting any error messsage?

Comment: what is the error you found?

Answer (score 0):

I am kinda in the same situation... hunting online, I see many users have got the same problem resolved by running a scan on their systems for malwares (they are working on windows systems). Not sure if malware attack possible on linux? If so, try running some anti-malware programs.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox in windows was playing up with random pop up windows appearing under the mouse. I loaded Ubuntu yesterday for the first time, very glitchy, Firefox works better but crashes on some websites so I downloaded Chromium, this seems to work OK.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
Delete the DSL or Wireless connection you are currently using and create a new one. That's all ! :-) 
Hope this helps !